# Java 2D array - How to assign an array as a value?

Tags: java, arrays

**Background**
I am doing a game project for my java class and we are using a grid system for the playing area. 50 wide by 25 tall. The squares are dynamically sized based on your monitor size and it involves a bit of math. I removed that from my example below so it is easier to look at.

What I currently decided to do is store the grid squares in a nice and simple 2D array so we can access and update the playing area as needed. Here is that code:

```
// Updates when told to, saves new values
public static void GridList() {
// Record which grid squares are open (0) or blocked (1)
// X = Row and Y = Column
for (int x = 0; x < 50; x++ ) {
    for ( int y = 0; y < 25; y++ ) {
        gridList[x][y] = 0;
    }
}
}
```

**Our Problem**
Now the trouble starts when I move on to saving order pairs (x,y) that represent the middle of these grid squares. For example, based on all the math we did to figure out your monitor size, we made a grid 50 wide by 25 tall and now need to save the (x,y) coordinates of the middle of those squares. This is so our AI knows where to move enemies; point by point as long as it is open.

This is what I have so far that saves X coordinates and Y coordinates in their own arrays:

```
public static void NodeList() {
    for (int x = 0; x < 50; x++ ) {
        for ( int y = 0; y < 25; y++ ) {
            nodeListX[x][y] = *Removed all the math.*;
            nodeListY[x][y] = *Removed all the math.*;
        }
    }
}
```

**What We Are Aiming To Have**
What I would really like to do is save an array for every grid square like this:

```
public static void NodeList() {
    for (int x = 0; x < 50; x++ ) {
        for ( int y = 0; y < 25; y++ ) {
            nodeList[x][y] = *array{x,y}*;
        }
    }
}
```

Is this possible in Java? I can't figure this out. I saw things mentioned about lists but we have not covered that yet so I am at a loss.

Comment: what do you mean by the notation array{x,y}?

Comment: I'm coming from a PHP background so what it means is that is an array. In PHP this would mean something like this: $gridSquare = $nodeList[x][y]; and then I could pull out the X and Y like so: $gridSquare[0]; $gridSquare[1]; It is hard for me to relate this to Java, it seems a 3D array is more what I'm looking for but have not yet tried it.

Comment: Instead of using an inner array, just use the class Coordinate. It's the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java doesn't really have a way to store a pair of numbers. But you could make a coordinate class like this:

```
`public class Coordinate
 int x;
 int y;

 public Coordinate(x,y)
 {
  this.x=x;
  this.y=y;
 }

 public int getX()
 {
  return x;
 }

 public int gety()
 {
  return y;
 }
`
```

Then you can just create an array of coordinates.

Comment: I'll need to look at this when I have more time but that doesn't seem like it would help much. I will still have two separate variables/ arrays that need calling and combining in loops to pull out my coordinates. I have 1250 ordered pairs that need saving and accessing as quick as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I don't see the problem with your or fdsa's solution. But if you're looking for another approach, you can always use a 3-dimensional array, with the third dimension containing 2 elements for X and Y:

```
public static void NodeList() {
    for (int x = 0; x < 50; x++ ) {
        for ( int y = 0; y < 25; y++ ) {
            int xPos = *Removed all the math.*;
            int yPos = *Removed all the math.*;
            nodeList[x][y] = new int[] {xPos, yPos};
        }
    }
}
```

Just make sure to declare `nodeList` as `int[][][]`.